# LXML - parse td content within tr tag

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, lxml

I want to parse each individual statistic from the yahoo finance tables for formatting purposes - when parsing the entire table the formatting is terrible!!  I am currently using the code below and I would have to repeat the 4 lines of contentA code slightly altered to retrieve the stats within each row of the table.  This is exemplified in the contentB variables below.  I refuse to believe this is the most efficient way to do so.  Any suggestions?

```
from lxml import html   

url = 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/is?s=MMM+Income+Statement&annual'

tree = html.parse(url)

contentA = tree.xpath("//table[@class='yfnc_tabledata1']/tr[1]/td/table/tr[2]/td[1]")[0].text_content().strip()
contentA1 = tree.xpath("//table[@class='yfnc_tabledata1']/tr[1]/td/table/tr[2]/td[2]")[0].text_content().strip()
contentA2 = tree.xpath("//table[@class='yfnc_tabledata1']/tr[1]/td/table/tr[2]/td[3]")[0].text_content().strip()
contentA3 = tree.xpath("//table[@class='yfnc_tabledata1']/tr[1]/td/table/tr[2]/td[4]")[0].text_content().strip()

contentB = tree.xpath("//table[@class='yfnc_tabledata1']/tr[1]/td/table/tr[3]/td[1]")[0].text_content().strip()
contentB1 = tree.xpath("//table[@class='yfnc_tabledata1']/tr[1]/td/table/tr[3]/td[2]")[0].text_content().strip()
contentB2 = tree.xpath("//table[@class='yfnc_tabledata1']/tr[1]/td/table/tr[3]/td[3]")[0].text_content().strip()
contentG3 = tree.xpath("//table[@class='yfnc_tabledata1']/tr[1]/td/table/tr[3]/td[4]")[0].text_content().strip()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `range` and `format`

```
for i in range(1,5):
    contentA = tree.xpath("//table[@class='yfnc_tabledata1']/tr[1]/td/table/tr[2]/td[{i}]".format(i=i))[0].text_content().strip()
    print(contentA)
```

Output

```
Total Revenue
31,821,000
30,871,000
29,904,000
```

---

```
for i in range(1,5):
    contentB = tree.xpath("//table[@class='yfnc_tabledata1']/tr[1]/td/table/tr[3]/td[{i}]".format(i=i))[0].text_content().strip()
    print(contentB)
```

Output

```
Cost of Revenue
16,447,000
16,106,000
15,685,000
```

EDIT

```
In [22]: d = {}

In [23]: d.setdefault('Revenue', [])
Out[23]: []

In [24]: for i in range(2,5):
   ....:     contentB = tree.xpath("//table[@class='yfnc_tabledata1']/tr[1]/td/table/tr[3]/td[{i}]".format(i=i))[0].text_content().strip()
   ....:     d['Revenue'].append(int(contentB.replace(',', '')))
   ....:     

In [25]: d
Out[25]: {'Revenue': [16447000, 16106000, 15685000]}
```

Comment: How would I freely format each variable that is returned?  For instance I want a dictionary where 

    Total Revenue : '31,821,000', '30,871,000', '29,904,000'

Comment: quick question - when you are using XPATH and you use the curly brackets  { i } what exactly is that telling the program?  Does this define it as a list in which you iterate with the for loop?

Comment: `{i}` has nothing to do with `xpath` but [`format`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html#format-examples)

Comment: Just had to think it through, makes sense now... Any way to switch those returned strings over to integers?